# how to relate computing power of attacker to transaction rate of attacker?

Tags: tangle, double-spending, white-paper

Assume that the merchant accepts the legitimate transaction when its cumulative weight becomes at least w_0, which happens t_0 time units after the original legitimate transaction. let μ stand for the computing power of the attacker and λ_a be the transactions issuing rate by the attacker. For a successful double-spend attack, page 18 of white paper states that μt_0 must be greater than w_0, how do we relate μ to λ_a or λ_a(μ)=??